# RestTemplate (Spring Boot Starter Parent 2.1.9.RELEASE) and jackson-dataformat-xml 2.10.0 is not parsing yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sss

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a maven project with spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.9.RELEASE,
jackson-dataformat-xml, jackson-core,
and jackson-databind v2.10.0.

I am using RestTemplate to get XML data and convert it to a POJO,
but the following exception is thrown:

`Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of ... (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2019-05-29T16:49:00.583')`

The xml has: `<dtAlteracao>2019-05-29T16:49:00.583</dtAlteracao>`

How to solve this issue,
please?

Comment: Show us your code, where you get this exception?

Comment: Could you show your `POJO` class and `XML` payload?

Comment: You need to give details about the class into which you are attempting to store the date.  The format you are receiving is ISO format without the timezone offset (I believe this is the LocalDateTime format), but may not be recognized as a valid format the the type into which you are attempting to store it (perhaps `java.sql.Date`).

Comment: My bad, it was misunderstand. I will delete this question. Please, see the GitLab group: https://gitlab.com/javatimegroup

Thanks for attention and help.

My apologizes.